# Подключение скрипта в исключительных случаях

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем здравствуйте! На сайте имеется отдельная категория со своим шаблоном. Есть скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var height = $(this).height();
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  if(scrollTop <= height) {
    $('html, body').delay(1500).animate({
      scrollTop: $(".cover").offset().top
    }, 600, 'easeOutQuint', function() {
    });
  }
});
```

Возможно ли каким-то образом сделать так, чтобы этот скрипт срабатывал исключительно только в случае, если посетитель открывает страницы данной категории переходя из вне этой категории? А соответственно при переходе по страницам внутри этой категории, или хотя бы как минимум в пределах сайта хттп://мойсайт.ру этот скрипт не срабатывал. Благодарю за комментарии!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.referrer
```

Данная строка содержит url предыдущей страницы. Можете проверить является ли она частью вашего сайта.
Также вы можете преобразовать эту строку в объект URL и манипулировать его частями (hostname, origin, hash и т.д.)

```
var url = new URL(document.referrer);
```

Подробнее [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer).

Comment: @LADYX достаточно проверить равен ли ориджин реферера и вашего сайта (если нет, то переход был с другого сайта) , а далее искать в пути реферера подстроку с ключевым словом (catalog для вашего случая) и если она есть, то навигация произошла внутри одного раздела.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно у вас категория имеет уникальный URL или какую-то часть URL, которая повторяется в пределах всех страниц данной категории. Получите текущий URL страницы при помощи

```
window.location.href
```

И проверьте, входит ли в эту строку данный фрагмент. Если фрагмент обнаружен - вы на нужной странице, нет - вы в каком-то другом разделе. Для того, чтобы сказать как это сделать, нужно больше подробностей об роутах вашего сайта.

Comment: или в самом php подключать jquery при необходимости.

Comment: А как выглядят другие страницы этой категории?  Они отличаются от хттп://мойсайт.ру/special/baby/, можем мы привязаться к URL, или есть страницы в этой категории, которые никак не отличаются от корня категории? Можно реферер извлечь или воспользоваться историей браузера, но это не очень надежно.

Comment: Тогда лучше воспользоваться реферером, как предлагает ниже Weks, имея в виду, что его могут подделывать или отсекать FireWall-ы на стороне пользователя.